# One AWS account for payment, another for maintenance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-lightsail

For a friend, I created a Lightsail instance with associated S3 buckets for the media on the site. I paid for it as I was setting it up.

Now I want to change it so my friend - through his account - pays for the instance and the S3 buckets. How do I do that, without transferring all ownership of them to him (so I can still maintain the site as needed)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking at it backwards - the person who owns the account - in this case your friend who is paying for it - should have full control of the account, and get the billing under his name/account, you as a developer should be given access to it to do maintenance/development etc, not the other way around.

In your setup, what happens if you get hit by the proverbial bus? Your friend (or really any customer) would have no access to his own data and no ability to hire someone else to takeover or help with maintenance when you are not there.

Comment: Yes, I see that now. But it's too late, as I created everything already.